# How to delete the Existing Records in table and insert new Value in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

This may be dumb question whenever I fetch the record from server need to delete the old records of the table and need to insert the new values into that table how can I do this! so far what I have tried is!

```
public void DashInsertorUpdate(DashBoardModel dashobjj){
        String query=" SELECT  * FROM " + DashBoardModel.DashBoardTable +  " WHERE " + DashBoardModel.DashBoardLable +"";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            DeleteDashboard(dashobjj);
        } else {
            InsertDashBoardLeadBySource(dashobjj);
        }

    }

 public void DeleteDashboard(DashBoardModel modelobj){
        db.execSQL(" DELETE FROM " + DashBoardModel.DashBoardTable + " WHERE " + DashBoardModel.DashBoardLable + "= '" + modelobj.getLabel() + "'");

    }
```

But its not deleting the existing records how can I do this can anyone help me out!

Comment: db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);

Comment: db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);

Comment: What is the select statement doing? You use a WHERE clause, but what is the condition and are you sure you are getting results from that query?

Comment: how to do first need to delete the existing records and then need to insert fresh records from server

Comment: @MedlinMoni you want delete all record or specific

Comment: @MedlinMoni: Is deletion is required ? because you can do it using `insertWithOnConflict ` without deleting row

Comment: whole record and insert the new records how can i do this

Comment: insertwithOnconfilic is not working i have tried that

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you want. Would INSERT OR REPLACE describe it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try these

```
public void deleteTypeDetails(){
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(Constants.TYPE_TABLE_NAME,"1",null);
            db.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks ganesh need to delete the existing record and insert fresh record whenever connection made with server

Comment: nooo what i need to do is whenever i make connection with server first need to delete the existing one and insert the new one how to do this

Comment: please try above answer

Answer (score 0):

if all records of your table must be deleted and replaced, I suggest this way:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

also you can delete one specific record using this code which can find that record using it's ID:

```
private void deleteDashboard(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String where = "id = ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{id + ""};

        try {
            db.delete(DashBoardModel.DashBoardTable, where, whereArgs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, according to your question, I think you are about to update records one by one with new data received from server, which this way could help you:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("field_name", value);

db.update(DashBoardModel.DashBoardTable, cv,
                        where, whereArgs);
```

By the way, I hope your table has a primary key and you can use where clause for finding the exact record. (even for delete or update)

Finally I suggest you to use new ORM available for Android like Realm, of DBFlow to avoid all these troubles. ;)